# iTunes Connect validation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app (v1.0) that I uploaded successfully a couple of weeks ago.

Now we have updated it (v1.1) but when I try to validate it I get "No suitable applications records were found."

I have added the version in iTunes Connect. Targets Bundle version and Bundle version string, short is set to 1.1

In the Organizer, after doing Archive, the two looks the same (except of course for the version number).

Thankful for any help.

PS.
It also doesn't validate the old file that was validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the status is "ready for upload".

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem.  A few more steps were needed in iTunes Connect.